# Obtaining Layer Activation from Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I have a neural network tensorflow estimator which I call `classifier`, and I would like to print out the activations from a layer in the network, called `pool5`.

In the model function, I call:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    predictions = {"last_layer": pool5}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
```

Then in the main script, I have

```
predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=input_fn)
print(predictions["last_layer"])
```

But the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/John/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/Estimator_5minutes.py", line 177, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/John/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/Estimator_5minutes.py", line 152, in main
    print(predictions["last_layer"])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the perfect answer, but here is what I did to solve the problem.

```
predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=input_fn))
scipy.io.savemat('C:/activations.mat', {"activations": predictions})
```